# Can I get my Witcher Gear back?

Tags: the-witcher-3

So I accidentally not knowing you can upgrade your Witcher Starting Gear dismantled it. Is there anyway of getting another chest? I know you can get better Witcher Gear, but I'm talking about the original Iconic gear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot recover the gear if you can't buy it back.

However...

You cannot currently upgrade the Witcher starting gear.

This was an odd rumour based on the fact that you upgrade the crafted Witcher gear, later on.

Examples: feline school armour, ursine school sword, etc.

Comment: Well, the starting armour has one upgrade actually (or at least it's used in a recipie) - but it's for level 4 I think, so it is rather unimportant in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't manage to find that on my play through. Is it the serpentine school equivalent?

Comment: Nope, it wasn't green-quality, just one of the armours with generic sounding names needed it as a base instead of a shirt.

Comment: No, the armor you start with the Kaer Mohren armor you upgrade it to green witcher armor

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, no, it's gone for good if you dismantled it.

Comment: To be honest, you didn't answer the question, you answered a certain part of it.

Comment: Is there a way of getting you witcher gear back? no there isn't. Complete answer to the complete question. If you intened on asking more, you should have

Comment: "Is there anyway of getting another chest? I know you can get better Witcher Gear, but I'm talking about the original Iconic gear."

And there's the 2nd part of the question which you didn't answer. So I did ask more.

Comment: Exactly, there is one question there (Can i get the armor back?), followed by a statement specifying the armor you're talking about. What is the second question? The only implicit question is "if yes, how?" but since the answer is no, that doesn't apply.

Comment: How is "Is there anyway of getting another chest?" Not the 2nd part of the question, I can't see how that can be a statement.

Comment: That's the first part of the question